# How to read nvarchar(x) into String when null values are allowed?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have a SQL table with a column of type `nvarchar(20)` and want to read that column using `SqlDataReader`. Looks like the only way to do this is to use `GetSqlChars()` followed by `ToSqlString()`:

```
 String result = reader.GetSqlChars(index).ToSqlString().Value
```

the problem is that if the stored value happens to be null (and that's valid for my case) I get

```
[SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.]
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString.get_Value() +3212527
```

so I have to first check what the value returned by `ToSqlString()` returns in `IsNull()`:

```
SqlString asSqlString = reader.GetSqlChars(index).ToSqlString();
String result = asSqlString.IsNull() ? null : asSqlString.Value;
```

which works but requires lots of extra code and looks really inelegant.

Is there a more elegant way to achieve the same effect?

Comment: Doesn't reader("ColumnName").ToString() handle this?

Comment: "Looks like the only way to do this is to use `GetSqlChars()`" -- As the answers you've been given show, no, you don't need that. Where did you find that you do? It would be interesting to see whether it's wrong, or simply doesn't mean what you think it means.

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps:

```
var value = reader.IsDBNull(index) ? null : reader.GetString(index);
```

Or even shorter:

```
var value = reader[index] as string;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`GetValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getvalue.aspx) method:

```
// define your query
string query = "SELECT YourField FROM dbo.YourTable WHERE ID = 1";

using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("......"))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
{
   conn.Open();

   using(SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
   {
       if(rdr.Read())
       {
          string fieldValue = rdr.GetValue(2).ToString();
       }
   }

   conn.Close();
}
```

[`GetString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring.aspx) method is specifically coded to throw an exception if the database value is null.  This is by design.
The docs for GetString state: 
     Call IsDBNull to check for null values before calling this method

On the other hand, if you use `GetValue()` and you end up with a `DBNull` object as your value, the `DBNull.ToString` method automatically returns `String.Empty`.